# Vue test blob object issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vue-testing-library

I am trying to convert string to blob but I keep getting `{}` instead

```
const workingCSV = "Hey, hello, world,"
const localVue = createLocalVue()
const wrapper = shallowMount(ModalAddCollectionCSV, {
  localVue,
  propsData: {
    visible: true,
  },
})
const fileDict = [{ file: new Blob([workingCSV]) }]
```

fileDict is always `[{file:{}}]`, I need it in that format because loadcsv reads the first file passed to it, but here the first file is always empty

Answer (score 0):

You should create your blob in this way:

```js
const csvData = [
  ['UPC', 'SKU', 'Description', 'Cost', 'Quantity', 'Bin location', 'Category', 'Primary supplier', 'Value'].join(';') // header row with names of the columns
].concat(originalItemsArray.map(item => [ // only extract the columns we need
  item.upc,
  item.sku,
  item.product_name,
  +item.cost || 0,
  +item.level || 0,
  item.bin_location,
  item.category_name,
  item.supplier_name,
  (+item.level || 0) * (+item.cost || 0),
].map(val => JSON.stringify(val)).join(';'))); // properly quote the value of each column

  const myBlob = new Blob([csvData.join('\r\n')], { type: 'text/csv;charset=cp1250;' });
```